# javascript for each (var A in B) error, B is an array of array

Tags: javascript

I found code:

```
var B = [];
var data = [];
data.push("string");
// ....
B.push(data);
// ... 
for each (var A in B){
    console.log(B);
    console.log(A);
    let obj = A[0].split("|", 3);
    console.log(objid[0]);
    console.log(objid[1]);
}
```

So B is an array of array, I printed B, it is like:

```
[
   [
      "1+!|6789|1234",
      "15:00"
   ],
   [
      "2+!|1234|4567",
      "16:00"
   ]
]
```

And I also printed `obj`:

```
["!1+", "6789", "1234"]
["2+!", "1234", "4567"]
```

which seems correct. And I run this code, it works fine and all functionality works well.
But my VScode complains it has syntax error, and I read this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/for_each...in

So I tried

1. remove `each` and use `of`
2. remove `each` and keep using `in`
3. keep `each` and use `of`

for 1, it just crashed and give me error:
`SyntaxError: missing ; after for-loop initializer`

for 2, I tried to print `A`, and I got `A` is `0`, which is obviously wrong.

for 3, it just crashed and give me error:
`SyntaxError: invalid for each loop`

So how should I change it? I guess the old code is correct just deprecated, and I need a replacement that works exact the same way as it. Thanks!

Comment: For 2: `for (var a in b)` sets `a` to the indexes, not the values.

Comment: @Barmar yes, so "for each(var a in b)" sets `a` to the values?  Seems yes, weird usage..

Comment: @Barmar, then why `for (var a of b)` did not work?

Comment: It should work. Are you sure you had VSCode set to allow EcmaScript 6 syntax?

Comment: @Barmar, you are right.. ES6 is enabled in my group, is there a way to fix it with ES5?

Comment: `for-of` is a new ES6 feature.

Comment: @Barmar, thanks.. but is there a way to fix it with ES5?

Comment: Use `for (var A in B)` and then use `B[A]` to get the element value.

Comment: But read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-such-a-bad-idea?lq=1

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the link. So I was thinking, in my case, if i have to find some way to replace `for each(var a in b)`, and to avoid `for..in` as you post, maybe I should use `var index;  for (index =0; index < B.length; index++)` and then `var A = B[index]`?  In this way, it's longer but seems safer than `for (var A in B)`..?

Comment: Yes, that's the preferred way.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks for the reply. But I just realize -- if i want to replace equally for `for each (var a in b)`, then i should use `for (var A in B)` then `B[A]` right? ... I mean, the code I posted in my last comment is better and preferred, but `for (var A in B)` is the equally replacement right? :)

Comment: Yes, that's what I said in my comment right before the link.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks so much! Appreciate it! But I am still bit confused about `for each...in`, I understand it iterates over property values(like in this case, it iterates values of the array), but in this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/for_each...in          I noticed it says "Never use a loop like this on arrays" but apparently it worked on arrays(like in my case it iterates all the values)...Does it mean `for each.. in` works for arrays just not recommended?

Comment: Yes, that's what it means. But it's deprecated so you shouldn't use it at all. This is the first time I've even seen it.

Comment: It's more than just deprecated, it has been completely removed from recent browser versions.

Comment: @Barmar thanks! Actually i was confused with it saying "Never use a loop like this on arrays. Only use it on objects"...   In my mind, it should work for both array and objects..So I was a bit confused.. but yes, no matter it's object or array, we should not use it at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
for (const A of B) {
    console.log(B);
    console.log(A);
    let obj = A[0].split("|", 3);
    console.log(objid[0]);
    console.log(objid[1]);
}
```

Comment: I understood that you only changed 'each' for 'off'. You need to change more than just the words;

Answer (score 0):

It's an array. Use [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach):

```js
B.forEach(A => {
  console.log(B);
  console.log(A);
  let obj = A[0].split("|", 3);
  console.log(obj[0]);
  console.log(obj[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

- For...of

*The for...of statement creates a loop iterating over iterable objects, including: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables. It invokes a custom iteration hook with statements to be executed for the value of each distinct property of the object.*

```
for (variavel of iteravel) {
  console.log(element);
}
```

- For...in

*The for...in statement iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (ignoring ones keyed by Symbols), including inherited enumerable properties.*

```
const object = { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 };

for (const property in object) {
  console.log(`${property}: ${object[property]}`);
}
```

- For each...in (DEPRECATED)

***The for each...in statement is deprecated as the part of ECMA-357 (E4X) standard. E4X support has been removed. Consider using for...of instead.***

- forEach

*The forEach() method executes a provided function once for each array element.*

```
const array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

array1.forEach(element => console.log(element));
```

- for

*The for statement creates a loop that consists of three optional expressions, enclosed in parentheses and separated by semicolons, followed by a statement (usually a block statement) to be executed in the loop.*

```
let str = '';

for (let i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  str = str + i;
}

console.log(str);
// expected output: "012345678"
```